# Proving that two periodic functions are orthogonal

Tags: trigonometry, fourier-series

Suppose we have a periodic function $f_K(\vec x)$.

We want to show that $\int {f_K^*(\vec x) f_{K'}(\vec x) d\vec x} = \delta_{KK'}$, where the integration is over the period of $f(x)$.

I know this has to do with Fourier series, one form of which is:

$$f(x) = \frac {a_0}{2} + \sum_{n=1}^N [a_n \cos(nx)+ b_n \sin(nx)] ,$$

where

$$a_n = \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(x)\cos(nx)dx, $$

$$b_n = \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(x)\sin(nx)dx .$$

I am unable to proceed because it looks to me as a circular logic. Cosines and Sines are themselves orthogonal functions, I do not understand how to use them to prove the orthogonality of another function which should depend - via Fourier Transform - on the orthogonality of the sines and cosines! I know, I am misunderstanding something here.

Comment: I don't follow your concern about circularity.  I could translate your question into finite-dimensional linear algebra as "I want to show that two vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ are orthogonal.  I know this has to do with the standard basis...the basis elements themselves are orthogonal.  I do not understand how to use them to prove the orthogonality of two other vectors which should depend -- via a choice of basis -- on the orthogonality of basis vectors!"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that cosines and sines are orthogonal.  Without knowing something about $f_K(\vec x)$ and $f_{K'}(\vec x)$they are not automatically orthogonal.  One way to prove it is to expand $f_K$ as a Fourier series, but that will only work if the relation between $f_K$ and $f_{K'}$ is right.  It is not circular, you are reducing the problem to one you have already solved.

Comment: We do know one thing about $f_k(x)$: it is periodic. Isn't that enough for the purpose here?

Comment: @ali8:  No, as Brian Rushton's example shows.  In the trig functions, within a period the function is as often positive as negative, but we are not given that.  Then the varying wavelength makes them orthogonal, but we are not given that either.

Comment: But if we expand f in sines and cosines...wouldn't that help? (We know the period of f(x))

Comment: @ali8:  That is one approach for proving it, if it is true. But $f_K(x)$ could be $K$ times the fractional part of $x$.  These are all periodic with period $1$ but are not orthogonal.  Or they could be $1+\sin (Kx)$ which are not orthogonal either.

Comment: I see. For some reason I though this is going to be easy as proving two Hermitian operators' wave functions are orthogonal.

Comment: @ali8:  When the operator is Hermitian, you have eigenvalues which are generally distinct, and that gives the key to proving orthogonality.  We don't have that structure for general periodic functions.

Answer (score 0):

Not all periodic functions are orthogonal; $\sin(x)$ is not orthogonal to $\sin(x)+\cos(x)$.